# Formatting json converted datetime string returned from github v3 in python

Tags: python, strftime

I have a python application that decodes json from github api v3. After the decode, my unicode date/time string looks like this:

u'2011-12-11T22:37:18Z'

How do I format this using something like strftime or the like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-12-11T22:37:18Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')`
```

Comment: Thank you. The complete expression for those who may be looking is: datetime.datetime.strptime(content['created_at'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').strftime('%m/%d/%Y@%H:%M:%S')